# Is every compact sifted $\infty$-category trivial?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

The paradigmatic sifted $\infty$-category to work with is the dual simplex category $\Delta^{op}$. Unfortunately (and unlike the analogous case of reflexive coequalizers in the 1-categorical setting), this $\infty$-category is not "finite". I suspect this is unavoidable:

**Question:** Let $C$ be an $\infty$-category which is [sifted](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sifted+%28infinity%2C1%29-category), and which is moreover [compact](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object) as an object of $Cat_\infty$. Does it follow that $C$ is "trivial" in the sense that there exists a [final](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+%28infinity%2C1%29-functor) functor $Idem \to C$?

Here $Idem$ is the walking [idempotent](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent), so that a functor $Idem \to D$ corresponds to an object in $D$ equipped with a (coherent) idempotent.

**Notes:**

- An equivalent way to say that $C$ admits a final functor from $Idem$ is to say that there exists a cocone on the identity functor on $C$.
- If the answer to my question is "yes", then it seems you can't usefully work with colimits which are *both* sifted *and* finite.
- This all stands in contrast to the 1-categorical setting, where the indexing category for reflexive coequalizers (which 1-categorically sifted, and does not admit a final idempotent) *is* compact as an object of $Cat$.
- By way of comparison, it is true (both 1-categorically and $\infty$-categorically) that any compact *filtered* category admits a final idempotent.
- I'd be interested in the variant question where instead of assuming $C$ to be *compact* as an object of $Cat_\infty$, we assume the more restrictive condition that $C$ is *finite* -- i.e. it is Joyal-equivalent to a finite simplicial set, or equivalently that it can be constructed from the arrow category and the empty category via a finite sequence of pushouts.